# How to set filter and also add a QPushButton to a QTableView in PyQt? i.e how to set two models to a QTableView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside

I am new to PyQt.
I have a `QLineEdit` and a `QTableView` in my window.
My requirements:

1. Whenever I type something in `QLineEdit`, the table has to show filtered results according to what I typed.
2. I want to add a QPushButton at last column of `QTableView`.

I have successfully implemented these requirements individually. But I am not able to add these two requirements simultaniously.

Here's my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
import sys

class Application(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0,0,700,200)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.searchBar = QLineEdit()
        self.table = QTableView()

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.searchBar)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.table)


        self.modelOfTable = QStandardItemModel()
        self.modelOfTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Date', 'Description', 'Cause', 'Category', 'Button'])
        self.table.setModel(self.modelOfTable)

        self.modelOfTable.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)) for i in range(5)])
        self.modelOfTable.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)) for i in range(4,9)])
        self.modelOfTable.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)) for i in range(7,12)])
        for i in range(3):
            self.table.setIndexWidget(self.modelOfTable.index(i, 5), QPushButton("button"))


        filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.modelOfTable)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.searchBar.textChanged.connect(filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)

        self.table.setModel(self.modelOfTable)

        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        # Setting the window to be in maximised mode
        #self.showMaximized()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

All the problem is in  `self.table.setModel` line.

If I write `self.table.setModel(self.modelOfTable)` in that line, Pushbutton is placed in last column but filter is not working.

[image: result is here]

If I write `self.table.setModel(self.modelOfTable)` in that line, filter is working but there is no pushbutton in last column.

[image: result is here]

How can I add both two requirements at a time?

Comment: You're always setting the model to `self.modelOfTable`, meaning that the filtering doesn't work. Maybe you meant `self.table.setModel(filter_proxy_model)`? Also, using filtering means that whenever an index is filtered out, the index widget will not be restored back once the index is shown again. What is the purpose of that button? Because you probably need to use an item delegate and set an appropriate editor for that.

Comment: The purpose of the button is... When i click a button, it has to show another page related to that row. And what is item delegate and how to use that? Could you give me some example for how to use item delegate and appropriate editor. It will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @JChandraKiran Re. delegates, please refer to the relevant [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).